# CakePHP how to retrieve data from another controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to show latest news titles on the main page of my site.
Main page is static and based on the Cake's default PagesController.

I have table, model, controller and view for news part of my site.

In the Cookbook I found the

```
Controller::requestAction
```

method, but it also says that it can cause a poor performance if I don't use cache.

As I know I also can create a method needed for all (or some) of my controllers in the AppController itself, but how I can link this method with specific model?

What is a proper OOP way to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to share logic/data between controllers your best bet is to use a component. Put your logic in your component and simply call the component's method from each of your controllers.

---

**Edit**

To access your model from your component, you can simply pass whichever model it is to your component's method. Example:

*Component*

```
public function fetchMyData($model) {
    return $model->find('all');
}
```

*Controller*

```
$mydata = $this->ComponentName->fetchMyData($this->ModelName);
```

Comment: ok if I'll make a component how I can access data from my model in the component?

Comment: @HugoDozois Components don't make use of the `$uses` variable like controllers do.

Comment: I probably did something wrong, I've created MyDataComponent.php in /app/Controller/Component/ with code you provided. Also I added public $components = array('MyData'); to my controller and then your code. But I get a Error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC 
File: app/Controller/Component/MyDataComponent.php

Comment: Did you make sure to put the function in a class? i.e. `class MyDataComponent extends Component`. Check out the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component) for creating a component

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's what you meant, but you can access models that arn't related to a specific controller by adding

```
public $uses = array('modelINeed');
```

in your controller's definitions. For more info, look at this [Controllers in cakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html), `CTRL + F` and look for "$uses", .

I do not suggest loading one controller into another. Use the models to retrieve data from the database!